# Xss set thread stack size for 1 thread, what is the limitation for all thread's stack size

Tags: java, multithreading, stack, jvm-arguments

I know how to set  stack size for java thread using -Xss, and we use it in our product.

But when there are lots of thread used in our application , and -Xss is set (we set to 512k for our usage). we will encounter error reporting unable to create new native thread. 
  it should be related to stack size , as when we set -Xss256k, the error gone.

My question is for 1 thread, Xss set stack size, but how about for all threads stack size?
what is the limitation of whole Thread's total  stack memory size?
i didn't find such JVM setting, while we do seems encounter such problem now.

Comment: There's no Java setting for stack size for all threads. You'll see when it runs out when the native platform tells you it can't create any more threads.

Comment: I suggest you look at a way to optimise the thread to use the stack less, if this s your limitation.  I assume you can't just add more memory.

Comment: Got it, Thanks .  So it may related to the underline OS's capability when creating Threads.  Each Threads uses resources including stack , and at some condition, can't create more threads. In our application example, when stack size is 512k and creating 100 threads will not work, while stack size 256k same threads works. We are writing load testing tool, and each thread's contents are specified by our user, so can't optimize threads.  Seems just  special JVM implementation and related OS limitation in this case.

Comment: To solve our problem, user needs to  user more powerful machine, or use less Threads or Stack ,etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-Xss` sets the *default* amount of virtual memory reserved for each new thread's stack.  (That is, for each new thread that is not given an explicit stack size through its constructor.)

There is no option to limit the *combined* stack sizes for all threads.

If setting `-Xss` down from 512K to 256K enables your program to create more threads, then your program must be creating an awful lot of threads.

What are all of those threads doing?

Are you sure you can't solve the problem using a limited number of threads in a *thread pool*?

Comment: we can't limit the thread.  our product is a load testing tool, which do need lots of thread for generate load for server to be tested

Comment: but still this is a good answer, limit thread should also be solution for most others who face such problem.    BTW:  for James mentioned set stack for separate thread: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507133/increasing-stack-space-of-a-single-worker-thread-in-java?rq=1